# php regex , preg match for special characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

How to `preg_match()` if a string has a special character?

The string will only accept letters and numbers and will not accept special characters such as `@ # $  ^ & * ( ) _ + ! { } : "` and others you can think of.

```
$specialCharacterRegex = "";

if(preg_match($specialCharacterRegex, $last_name, $match)){
    echo ("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
    window.alert('Invalid last name. Please check, make sure special character...');
    window.location.href='./../MEMBERS/members.php';
    </script>");
}
```

Comment: It might be easier to make a negated character class for the characters you want to allow e.g. `$specialCharacterRegex = "/[^A-Za-z0-9]/";`

Comment: `$specialCharacterRegex  = "/\\W/";`

Comment: @Toto that would allow `_`, which OP doesn't want.

Comment: @Nick: `$specialCharacterRegex  = "/[\\W_]/";` ;-)

Answer (score -1):

you can check like this,

```
$string = "hai1@";
echo preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $string);
```

if you get 0 then it has special characters
if 1 then only numbers and letters as expected